# Which one database will be easy to use for a project based on ASP.NET /MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sqlite

I am working on my final year project. It is a web based system that is based on ASP.NET/MVC. I want to start from database but I have a little confusion which database to use from Sql, sqlite and sqlite3 that is not complicated and good for me to finish my project on time. can you please give me your suggestions which database should I choose?

Comment: MSSQL also known as sequel server. Forget sqlite and sqlite3. Download SQL Express and start your project

Answer (score 1):

I would use SQL Server 2008R2 +, furthermore I would use Entity Framework to access it as ASP.NET/MVC fits well alongside it in the Microsoft stack.

Further developer info on Entity Framework
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/ef.aspx

You will have to write a lot less database access code using this approach

Answer (score 1):

I recommend...

## SQL Server + EntityFramework

[EntityFramework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937709.aspx) is an Object/Relational Mapping (ORM) framework that enables developers to work with relational data as domain-specific objects, eliminating the need for most of the data access plumbing code that developers usually need to write.

Some Pros

- Much faster to build the DAL (love not writing the SQL queries!)
- Much easier to maintain
- No longer need to remember to parse my input before building an in-line sql statement, which means less chance of a SQL injection attack (of course, it's still possible depending on your queries, but much less likely)

would also encourage you to read [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/115136/should-we-use-entity-framework).

Answer (score 0):

asp.net / mvc is geared towards SQL (even compact) whereas sqllite is very widely deployed.  I would use SQL if I was using asp.net.